# Use a output CTE inline in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to use a CTE inline, like a function but I cannot create a function as I have only read only access to the database. Is there another way to do this simply?

Query:

```
SELECT SuiteID,ParentSuiteID FROM tbl_Suite;
```

The resultset is like:

```
SuiteID ParentSuiteID
1   0
4   1
5   4
6   4
7   4
8   4
9   4
10  4
11  4
```

Now I am looking for a resultset where:

```
SuiteID ParentSuiteID Level1ParentID
1   0                 0 
4   1                 0
5   4                 1
6   4                 1 
7   4                 1
8   4                 1 
9   4                 1
10  4                 1 
11  4                 1
```

WITH THE CTE below, I am able to fetch the Level1Parent if I pass the SuiteID

```
;WITH HIERARCHY AS
( select T1.SuiteID,T1.Title,T1.ParentSuiteID, 0 Level FROM tbl_Suite(nolock) T1
  Where T1.ParentSuiteID = 0 AND T1.PlanID = '404'
  UNION ALL
  select T2.SuiteID,T2.Title,T2.ParentSuiteID,Level+1 
  from tbl_Suite(nolock) AS T2
  INNER JOIN HIERARCHY AS H
  ON T2.ParentSuiteID = H.SuiteID
 )

,CTE_A(SuiteID,Title,ParentSuiteID,Level) AS
(
     select H2.SuiteId, H2.Title, H2.ParentSuiteId, H2.Level
     from Hierarchy H2 
     --INNER JOIN #X_Temp X
     --ON H2.SuiteID = X.SuiteID  
     where H2.SuiteID = 10820
     UNION ALL
     select H2.SuiteId, H2.Title, H2.ParentSuiteId, H2.Level
     from Hierarchy H2 JOIN CTE_A On H2.SuiteID = CTE_A.ParentSuiteID 
)

SELECT SuiteID FROM CTE_A WHERE level = 1
```

My question is:

A) How do I pass the SuiteID as an inline subquery to the recursive CTE query?
B) How do I combine the resultset as shown above?

Comment: You might take a peek at this article before you continue littering your queries with NOLOCK. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: What would really help is if you could provide the ddl for your tables and sample data along with the desired output. As it is right now that first query is simply too long and confusing to decipher and it is not at all clear to me what you are trying to do. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hi Sean, in the first query I am trying to fetch the resultset on which I intend apply aggregation. Only the column SuiteID is significant for this query whereby it has a parent child relationship, so I need to find the second level parent for every SuiteID which is what the CTE below does. What I am not able to do is combine both the codes to have an output as single resultset.

Comment: See my last comment if you really want some help.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the feedback Sean. I have rephrased my question.

Answer (score 0):

Still not totally sure what you want here but I think you already have the code for it 99.99999%. Ideally you would post something consumable for data. Along these lines.

```
create table #tbl_suite
(
    SuiteID int
    , ParentSuiteID int
)

insert #tbl_suite
select 1,   0 union all
select 4,   1 union all
select 5,   4 union all
select 6,   4 union all
select 7,   4 union all
select 8,   4 union all
select 9,   4 union all
select 10,  4 union all
select 11,  4
```

Then all anybody has to do is work on the query and not the setup and the query. Using your cte this is pretty much done. I had to remove Title and PlanID since they are not in your new sample data.

```
WITH HIERARCHY AS
( 
    select T1.SuiteID
        --, T1.Title
        , T1.ParentSuiteID
        , 0 Level 
    FROM #tbl_Suite(nolock) T1
    Where T1.ParentSuiteID = 0 
        --AND T1.PlanID = '404'
UNION ALL
    select T2.SuiteID
        --, T2.Title
        , T2.ParentSuiteID
        , Level + 1 
    from #tbl_Suite(nolock) AS T2
    INNER JOIN HIERARCHY AS H ON T2.ParentSuiteID = H.SuiteID
)
select SuiteID
    , ParentSuiteID
    , case when Level = 0 then Level else Level -1 end as Level
from HIERARCHY
```

Comment: Hi Sean, I think I am trying to get the result set as a new column in my previous query as I must determine the first parent of every suiteid. Not sure if I am explaining this right. You see, a suiteid can roll up to a parent, which would again have a parent, which would again rollup till it reaches root. The CTE must be invoked for all the records so as to determine the L1Parent record. I understand, this must be very confusing.

Comment: Well than post some sample data that represents the issue, the desired output and an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your data. Is SuiteId= 1 on level 0 or level 1?

In your resultset

```
SuiteID ParentSuiteID Level1ParentID
1   0                 0 
4   1                 0
5   4                 1
6   4                 1 
7   4                 1
8   4                 1 
9   4                 1
10  4                 1 
11  4                 1
```

You return SuiteID=1 as Level1ParentID for members suiteid in (5,..,11), but wouldn't suiteid=1 be the level1parent for Suiteid=4?

If SuiteID=4 is level1, then your resutl should be:

```
SuiteID ParentSuiteID Level1ParentID
1   0                 0 
4   1                 0
5   4                 4
6   4                 4 
7   4                 4
8   4                 4 
9   4                 4
10  4                 4 
11  4                 4
```

This piece of code gives the required result. I use your original CTE for Hierarchy, and record the Level1ParentId in the hierarchy.

If we start with suiteid=1 as level1 then we get this result:

```
SuiteID ParentSuiteID   Level1ParentId
1   0   0
4   1   1
5   4   1
6   4   1
7   4   1
8   4   1
9   4   1
10  4   1
11  4   1
```

If we start with level 0 then we get:

```
SuiteID ParentSuiteID   Level1ParentId
1   0   0
4   1   0
5   4   4
6   4   4
7   4   4
8   4   4
9   4   4
10  4   4
11  4   4
```

This is the code:

```
;with tbl_Suite as
(
select * from (values
(1 ,  0 ,'title 1' ,'404')
,(4 ,  1,'title 4' ,'404')
,(5 ,  4,'title 5' ,'404')
,(6 ,  4,'title 6' ,'404')
,(7 ,  4,'title 7' ,'404')
,(8 ,  4,'title 8' ,'404')
,(9 ,  4,'title 9' ,'404')
,(10,  4,'title 10','404')
,(11,  4,'title 11','404')
) s(SuiteID,ParentSuiteID,Title,PlanId))
,HIERARCHY AS
( select T1.SuiteID,T1.Title,T1.ParentSuiteID, 0 Level,0 Level1ParentId FROM tbl_Suite T1
  Where T1.ParentSuiteID = 0 AND T1.PlanID = '404'
  UNION ALL
  select T2.SuiteID,T2.Title,T2.ParentSuiteID,Level+1 
    ,case when Level=1 then t2.ParentSuiteID else Level1ParentId end 
  from tbl_Suite AS T2
  INNER JOIN HIERARCHY AS H
  ON T2.ParentSuiteID = H.SuiteID
 )
select a.SuiteID,a.ParentSuiteID,b.Level1ParentId from tbl_Suite a
inner join HIERARCHY b
on a.SuiteID=b.SuiteID
```